# how to remove centos 7 gui?

Tags: centos, centos7, graphical-user-interface

Recently I installed centos 7 with GUI. 
now I want to remove that GUI like was I hadn't chosen that? because I need more space on my disk.

I tried many times but I failed. could anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo yum groupremove "GNOME Desktop"
```